# c++ std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> . How to loop set values?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, set

I have declared a set inside a map in c++ as `std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>`. How to loop to access or print the set values ?

Comment: Maybe you should be using [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to iterate a `std::map` or a `std::set` individually, you should have no troubles iterating them in combination. Note that if you iterate a `std::map` using a range-based `for` loop, you're iterating `std::pair<K, V>`s where `K` is the (`const`-qualified) type of the key and `V` the type of the values.  If you only want to iterate a single set (associated with a a single key), simply access that element and iterate it as normal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int
main()
{
  auto stuff = std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> {
    {"fruits",     {"apple", "banana", "orange"}},
    {"vegetables", {"carrot", "cucumber"}},
    {"nuts",       {"peanut", "walnut", "hazelnut", "coconut"}},
  };
  // Iterate over a single set
  for (const auto& s : stuff["fruits"])
    std::cout << s << "\n";
  std::cout << "\n";
  // Iterate over the whole data structure
  for (const auto& pair : stuff)
    {
      std::cout << pair.first << ":";
      for (const auto& s : pair.second)
        std::cout << " " << s;
      std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
apple
banana
orange

fruits: apple banana orange
nuts: coconut hazelnut peanut walnut
vegetables: carrot cucumber
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably that you have a `std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>`, you can print the elements of the contained `set`s with a double ranged for loop as the example below:

```
std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> mp {{"1", {"1", "2", "3"}}, 
                                                 {"2", {"4", "5", "6"}}};

for(auto &&p : mp) {
  for(auto &&s : p.second) std::cout << s << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BXBW8MEhy1QgVfmg)

Or if you want something more fancy to impress your boss you could use a single ranged for loop with `std::copy` and `std::ostream_iterator`:

```
std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> mp {{"1", {"1", "2", "3"}}, 
                                                 {"2", {"4", "5", "6"}}};

for(auto &&p : mp) {
  std::copy(std::begin(p.second), std::end(p.second), 
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout," "));
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/O6SNLsHq7HK00ZUI)

edit:

> The goal is we have a table with camera name and specs as
>   {std::map> cameraSpec {{"camera1,
>   {"Spec1", "Spec2", "Spec3"}}, {"camera2", {"Spec2", "Spec4",
>   "Spec6"}}}; and I want to write a code to check which specification is
>   highly desirable to the user ? Something similar to finding the
>   frequency of a word from the given table. How to access the specs?

### How to access individual elements of the map

Say you want to access an existent element in the map (i.e., you're sure the specific key exists). You could use the `map`'s subscript operator in the following way:

```
for(auto &&s : mp["camera2"]) {
  // you loop over elements {"spec2", "spec4", "spec6"}
}
```

That is, `mp["camera2"]` will return a reference to set in the map with values `{"spec2", "spec4", "spec6"}` under the key "camera2".

If you're not sure that a key exists in the map, then use the member function `map::find`. That is, first query the map if specific key you're looking for exists in it and then access the elements of the value/set in the same way as shown above:

```
auto it = mp.find("camera2");
if(it != mp.end()) {
  for(auto &&s : it->second) {
    // you loop over elements {"spec2", "spec4", "spec6"}
  }
}
```

Notice that if key "camera2" exists in your map, then `map::find` will return an iterator pointing to element associated with that particular key.

Now, the elements of the map are of type `std::pair<const key_type, value_type>` (in our case `std::pair<const std::string, std::set<std::string>>`).

If the key is not found `std::map::find` is going to return an iterator pointing to one pass the end element of the map.

`std::pair` has two members `std::pair::first` and `std::pair::second`. In our case `std::pair::first` value is equal to the key's value (i.e,. "cammera2") and `std::pair::second` is equal to the value under that key (i.e., the `std::set` with values `{"spec2", "spec4", "spec6"}`). That is why in the loop shown above we iterate over `it->second` (i.e., the value/set under key "cammera2").

Comment: Is there a benefit to using r- value references here vs. const references?

Comment: @FredLarson is good habbit to use `auto&&` in for ranged loop. In this particular case it makes no difference.

Comment: @Tanya OK, what's the question?

Comment: @101010 Thank you so much. That was a good explanation. I appreciate it.